# how to write generics extensions for standart objects in java?

Tags: java, generics

I beginner in Java and I ask tell me some words about Java tradition of writing generic code. I wrote helper class for pushing items into generic sorted collections in code below and I want to know it is accepted? Or I should extends some base class of collections? Or other ways to welcome more in Java?

```
package com.rkovalev.Helper;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class ListExtensions {
    public static <T> void addOnCompare(List<T> collection, T item, Comparator<T> comparator) {
        synchronized(collection) {
            int i = 0;
            int size = collection.size();
            if (size == 1) {
                int diff = comparator.compare(item, collection.get(0));
                switch(diff) {
                case 1: i++; break;
                default: break;
                }
            } else {
                int range = size - 1;
                i = size / 2;
                int left = 0; 
                int right = range;
                while(true) {
                    if (i <= 0) { i = 0; break; }
                    if (i > range) { i = range; break; }
                    int diff = comparator.compare(item, collection.get(i));
                    if (diff == 0) break;
                    else { 
                        if (diff == -1) right = i;
                        if (diff == 1) left = i;
                        int near = i + diff; 
                        if (near < 0) { i = 0; break; }
                        if (near > range) { i = range + 1; break; }
                        int diff_near = comparator.compare(item, collection.get(near));
                        if (diff_near == 0) { i = diff_near; break; }
                        if (diff_near == diff) {
                            int step = (right-left)/2;
                            if (step == 0) step = 1;
                            switch(diff){
                            case -1:
                                right = i;
                                i = i - step; break;
                            case 1: 
                                left = i;
                                i = i + step; break;
                            }
                        } else if (diff > diff_near) { 
                            i = near; break; 
                        } else { break; }           
                    }
                }
            }
        collection.add(i, item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are asking for a code review, consider posting to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make extra "generic" functionality available for all collection classes, then writing the functionality as a static method in a "helper" class is the right way to go.

Adding the method to a base class of the existing collection classes would not work.  It would entail modifying the standard Java class library, and nobody in their right mind would do that.  (It is technically possible, but you would be creating a portability nightmare for your code.  Not to mention legal issues if you used the trademarked term "Java" in connection with your code.)